# Node - Check to see if a directory exists

Tags: node.js

This should be a fairly simple one to answer I would hope, however it's got me stumped - maybe I've been staring at too much code today!

I am trying to do a simple if statement which checks to see if a folder exists.  If the folder doesn't exist, make it, if it does, delete the content.

The problem I am having is that if the directory doesn't exist, then the callback (stats) is undefined.  With fs.exist it would be quite simple, but since its deprecated, I wanted to ensure this was future proofed.

```
var seriesid = 5;
      fs.stat("temp/" + seriesid, function (err, stats){
        if(!stats.isDirectory()){
          fs.mkdir("temp/" + seriesid);
          console.log('Folder doesn\'t exist, so I made the folder ' + seriesid);
          callback();
        }
        else if (err != 'ENOENT') {
          callback(err);
        }
        else {
          // TODO: Folder exists, delete contents
          console.log('Does exist');
          callback();
        }
      });
```

Any help on how to accomplish this would be appreciated

Comment: Check your `err` _first_. It's very likely you have encountered an error if `stats` is `undefined`.

Comment: 1. You should check for errors first. 2. If it doesn't exist, stats is undefined

Comment: Apologies, I've just realised that as I hit submit, so I have edited my question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check `err` first. Then check `isDirectory()`

```
fs.stat("temp/" + seriesid, function (err, stats){
  if (err) {
    // Directory doesn't exist or something.
    console.log('Folder doesn\'t exist, so I made the folder ' + seriesid);
    return fs.mkdir("temp/" + seriesid, callback);
  }
  if (!stats.isDirectory()) {
    // This isn't a directory!
    callback(new Error('temp is not a directory!'));
  } else {
    console.log('Does exist');
    callback();
  }
});
```

Comment: in case you don't want to deal directly with `fs`, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if stats exist before doing !stats.isDirectory()